# Using a loop to call data from an API

Tags: r

I've only recently started using R, and find myself really missing the old `i` from Stata. I'm trying to call some data, which you do country by country, for a list of countries, and create a data frame for each country. I can't figure out how to make sure the loop variable is recognized though. The below doesn't work but shows what I'm trying to do, where I've put `sym(i)` where I'd intuitively reach for `i`.

```
partners <- list('World', 'AUSTRAL', 'CANADA', 'RUSSIA', 'MONGOLA', 'INDNSIA')

for (p in partners) {
  print(p)
  my_data <- GET(
  "http://98.124.79.80/tdm/api/api.asp?username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&flow=B&reporter=CN&partners=sym(i)&periodBegin=202011&periodEnd=202111&encoding=UTF8"
    )
  http_type(my_data)
  my_databin <- content(my_data, "raw")
  writeBin(my_databin, "sym(i).txt")
  china_sym(i) <- read.csv("sym(i).txt", header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do and what the `i` from Stata does that feels incompatible here, but I think the problem is that you're trying to loop through with two different variables, whereas you can use one variable instead. Rather than looping through partners, using each string in partners, index through and use "i"

```
partners <- list('World', 'AUSTRAL', 'CANADA', 'RUSSIA', 'MONGOLA', 'INDNSIA')

for (i in 1:length(partners)) { # goes through the index of each country in 'partners'
  print(partners[[i]]) # will print the ith value in partners
  my_data <- GET(
  "http://98.124.79.80/tdm/api/api.asp?username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&flow=B&reporter=CN&partners=sym(i)&periodBegin=202011&periodEnd=202111&encoding=UTF8"
    )
  http_type(my_data)
  my_databin <- content(my_data, "raw")
# Use paste0 to create the names you are assigning output to
  writeBin(my_databin, paste0("sym(", i, ").txt"))
# Here it won't work to assign the read.csv with an operator (<-) using paste, so use assign
  assign(paste0("china_sym(", i, ")"), read.csv(paste0("sym(", 1, ").txt"), header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = "."))
}
```

This then assigns the read.csv to object of the form `` `china_sym(i)` ``